# UX best practices for a help desk/ticketing system? Views and steps

Tags: website-design, information-architecture, workflow

I am building a "help desk/ticketing system" app from the ground up. I am quickly finding out that I am reinventing the wheel in terms of workflow for the admin and users.

Where can I find best practices for things like ticket workflows and UI flow? For example, after a user submits a ticket, what happens? Should they see a dashboard view? When does the user get an auto email stating his ticket is in the queue? Etc!

Comment: I don't think there's any best practices from a UX perspective. I believe this should be a bespoke solution. Maybe this can help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlxgZXSRewU

Comment: Whenever I'm looking for "best practices" I spend an afternoon browsing other websites to see what everyone else does. Throw out the bad ones and what's left is best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are already so many ticket systems out there. Why waste your time and reinvent  the wheel? IMHO the only reason to do it anyway could be to offer *new* value. This requires defining a target user group, doing user research there and market research to find out which user goal is not met yet. Then design and build a new or adapt an existing solution in close contact with your users to ensure you fill the gap. Otherwise you will spend much time to invent the 1001st ticket system with a great chance that nobody will care about it.